# AS3 MOVING OBJECT ON SPECIFIC FRAME

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

so i've been working on this game for a week now and i dont have any coding background at all so im trying to find tutorial here and there.. then i come up with this problem ...

so what i wanna do is move the object (CHARA) to the right when i hit frame 80 inside (CHARA,which is a nested movieClip with 99 frames btw ) then move it back to original position when i hit frame 99...
the problem is anything i do doesn't make my object move at all (movieClip still played btw) what did i do wrong here? did i just put the code at the wrong position ?? (CHAR is moved only if i put the code x= directly inside frame 80 but i try using class here)

here is my code,sorry i know its messy its my first code i try my best here

```
package {

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        public var CHARA:CHAR = new CHAR;//my main char
        public var rasen:Rasen_button = new Rasen_button;//the skill button
        public var NPCS:NPC = new NPC;// the npc

        public function Main() {
            var ally:Array = [265,296];//where me and my ally should be
            var jutsu:Array = [330,180];// where the buttons should be
            var enemy:Array = [450,294];//where the enemies should be

            addChild(NPCS);
            NPCS.x = enemy[0];
            NPCS.y = enemy[1];
            NPCS.scaleX *=  -1;

            addChild(rasen);
            rasen.x = jutsu[1];
            rasen.y = jutsu[0];

            addChild(CHARA);
            CHARA.x = ally[0];
            CHARA.y = ally[1];
            rasen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f2_MouseOverHandler);
            function f2_MouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
                CHARA.gotoAndPlay(46); //here is the problem
                if (CHARA.frame == 80)
                {
                    CHARA.x = ally[1]; //just random possition for now
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` statement is inside a click handler (`f2_MouseOverHandler`), so it only gets executed when a user clicks `rasen`, not necessarily when the playback reaches frame `80`. This is a common beginner mistake related to timing and code execution. The most straight forward solution is to write some code that will execute every frame using an `ENTER_FRAME` handler:

```
        rasen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f2_MouseOverHandler);
        function f2_MouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            CHARA.gotoAndPlay(46); //here is the problem

            // add an ENTER_FRAME handler to check every frame
            CHARA.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, chara_EnterFrameHandler)
        }
        function chara_EnterFrameHandler(event:Event):void {
            if (CHARA.currentFrame == 80)
            {
                CHARA.x = ally[1]; //just random possition for now

                // remove the ENTER_FRAME after the condition is met
                // so it stops executing each frame
                CHARA.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, chara_EnterFrameHandler);
            }
        }
```

Comment: still not moving... let me explain .so in my CHARA object there is nested 99 frames movieClip with 2 stage iddle(1-42) and jutsu (43-99) when i click button rasen i want to play jutsu which in frame 80 my char should be moved to the front of the enemy then get back to its place after i hit frame 99.my code does make jutsu animation played,but the object just stand on its original place.

Comment: when i try to write if (CHAR.frame==1){trace("aadd")} it works but if i change 1 to anything else it doesn't, so i think the problem is my code doesn't listen to my object frames.instead it listen to the main stage.which is just 1 frame. so how did i use the object frames instead of the stage frames?? thanks btw

Comment: It's hard to follow. All I can say is that if you move an object in code (like `Char.x = ` then timeline animation for that object will no longer work. You can only do one or the other.

Comment: found the answer.... its just i need tu use currentFrame instead of frame ... i did use your code so thanks